# Why does Fujin choose to talk the way she does?

Tags: final-fantasy

In *Final Fantasy VIII*, Fujin talks using one-word sentences throughout most of the game.

[image: Fujin expressing anger]

However, close to the end of the game, she uses much longer sentences when she is pleading with Seifer to stop what he is doing.

[image: Fujin pleading with Seifer]

Now it's obvious that it's a decision on her part to talk like in the first screenshot, and while I can assume she only makes "small talk", is it explained why she uses one word most of the time which can be read as yelling (all caps)? Is it like this in the Japanese version?

Comment: Until disc 3 or so, Fujin speaks only in kanji in the Japanese version.